# Trasform cUrl PHP in cUrl C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, curl

I have this cUrl command for PHP:

```
curl --user AUTH_KEY:AUTH_SECRET -XPOST https://api.smshosting.it/rest/api/sms/send \
-d "from=mrossi" \
-d "to=393480000000" \
-d "text=Test Sms"
```

POST type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Info at: https://www.smshosting.it/it/docs/sms-rest-api/invio

but now i need use it in C# .Net 4.5.

I have no idea where to start though, I do not think it's complicated but I have never used the curl in C #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string url = "https://api.smshosting.it/rest/api/sms/send";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            string authInfo = "XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("from=XXXX&to=XXXXXX&text=XXXXX");
            Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            reqstr.Close();
```